# How to reference stylesheet from same domain?

Tags: css, directory, stylesheet

So I have the following PHP file in this directory: http://website.com/website/test/form.php

In the `<head>` tag of `form.php`, I have the following:
`<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="http://website.com/css/style.css" />`

When I visit http://website.com/css/style.css, the contents of the stylesheet appears fine, so why doesn't the web browser load this stylesheet? **The website is not https.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try href="css/style.css" instead.

Comment: This won't work for a page that is nested 3 folders deep.